# Phasing haplotypes

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics

I'm new to this area (but not to programming & algorithmics) and I want to help a friend to solve a problem (I don't need source code, I just want to understand the problem itself).

He needs a cycle to phase haplotypes ("I need find haplotype pattern(s) from SNP string"). He also said "The method is simple, I need to compare homozygot combinations (AA, BB) in sequence with haplotype chains. And ignore heterozygot pairs (AB) at their right positions."

An an input he has a SNP string and a bunch of haplotypes strings (array).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than re-explaining the basics of haplotype phasing, I will refer you to useful documentation.
One of the first works on haplotype phasing has been perfromed by Andrew Clark. You can find [here](https://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci2951-n/resources/AACB2014-clark_phasing.pdf) a nice slide presentation detailing the problem.
Useful discussion is going on [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/551/) on Biostars.
I suggest you to use of the several approaches that have already been developed: my favorites are Beagle and fastPHASE.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do it in PHP (really great on working with strings)